# Laravel: Validation not working - update method

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a problem with validation in update method. In create one it is ok, but when I try to edit, validation does not pass. Here is it:

```
public function update($id, array $data)
{   
    $quote = $this->find($id);

    if( isset($data['live_date']) ){
        $data['live_date'] = $this->_parseDate($data['live_date']);
    }

    $this->validator = new QuoteValidator($quote);
    $this->validate($data);

    try{     
        $quote->update($data);
        $quote->tracks()->sync($data['tracks']);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $ex){
        Log::error($ex->getMessage());
        throw new ProcessingDataException('An error occured.');
    }   

}
```

and here is the form in my view:

```
<div class="row">
    @if (!isset($qoute) || !isset($quote->live_date))
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::label('live_date[date]', 'Go-Live Date', ['class' => 'control-label', 'readonly' => 'readonly'] ) !!}
        {!! Form::text('live_date[date]', \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->format('m/d/Y'), ['class' => 'form-control date-picker']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::label('live_date[time]', 'Go-Live Time', ['class' => 'control-label', 'readonly' => 'readonly'] ) !!}
        {!! Form::text('live_date[time]', \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->format('H:i'), ['class' => 'form-control time-picker']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
@else
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::label('live_date[date]', 'Go-Live Date', ['class' => 'control-label', 'readonly' => 'readonly'] ) !!}
        {!! Form::text('live_date[date]', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($quote->live_date)->format('m/d/Y'), ['class' => 'form-control date-picker']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {!! Form::label('live_date[time]', 'Go-Live Time', ['class' => 'control-label', 'readonly' => 'readonly'] ) !!}
        {!! Form::text('live_date[time]', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($quote->live_date)->format('m/d/Y'), ['class' => 'form-control time-picker']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
@endif
</div>
```

It is just throwing an exception, when I have left empty fields, but when all the fields are populated with data, it is successful updated, no matter of rules in validation .

Comment: $data goes undefined if left empty.

Comment: when data goes undefined, it must throws validation messages from my validator just like in create case, but that's not happened.

Comment: What does `QuoteValidator` look like?

Comment: $this->rules = [
            'content'  => 'required',
            'tracks'   => 'required',
            'live_date' => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y H:i|after:now'
        ];

Comment: add the entire `QuoteValidator` file to your question.